# Submit fires even if email.value == ""

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple form where a user submits a video, alongside their email address. I'd like to make it so that the person can not submit the form until they have filled in the email and saved the video.

The video part is working, but when I test with an empty email, it still seems to submit. The code is below, and the live version is at http://www.atlas-china.com/record-your-multi-lingual-abilties/

Help much appreciated!

```
// Global variable to hold player's reference.
var _Nimbb;

// Global variable to hold the guid of the recorded video.
var _Guid = "";

// Event: Nimbb Player has been initialized and is ready.
function Nimbb_initCompleted(idPlayer) {
    // Get a reference to the player since it was successfully created.
    _Nimbb = document[idPlayer];
}

// Event: the video was saved.
function Nimbb_videoSaved(idPlayer) {
    _Guid = _Nimbb.getGuid();
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Get the data from the form.  Check that everything is completed.
    $('#video_submit').click(function (e) {

        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var video_title = document.getElementById("video_title").value;
        var form = document.myForm;

        // Make sure the email is specified.
        if (email.value == "") {
            alert("Please enter your email to proceed.");
            return;
        }

        // Verify that the video is not currently recording.
        if (_Nimbb.getState() == "recording") {
            alert("The video is being recorded. Please wait.");
            return;
        }

        // Check that video has been recorded.
        if (_Guid == "") {
            alert("You did not save the video.  Click save.");
            return;
        }

        // Set the guid as hidden parameter.
        form.guid.value = _Guid;

        var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&guid=' + _Guid + '&video_title=' + video_title;
        //alert (dataString);return false;  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/send.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                    .hide()
            }
        });
        document.forms["myForm"].submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: No matter the result of this check, you must verify the result on the server.

Comment: What if you `return false;`?

Comment: Why do you do both the ajax post *and* submit the form?

Comment: Hey Pointy, it's because I'd like the ajax to send data over to Zapier, which emails the data and does a bunch of cool stuff with it. However, I also want the person to be redirected to a thank you page.

Comment: email.value == "" - using "==" will attempt to convert the types of both arguments to the same type. Use "===" instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons.

Comment: Hey guys, I made the suggested updates, but it still seems to be submitting. However, this only happens with the email value, every other check stops it. What do you think might be the cause?

Comment: Ok, I looked at your live site. "email" = "", whereas "email.value" = undefined. Try changing your code to : if (email == "") {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing your live site...

```
email = "" // Empty string
```

Whereas

```
email.value = undefined
```

Try changing your code to

```
if (email === "") {
    alert("Please enter your email to proceed.");
    return;
}
```

I assume you are doing **.value** twice by mistake as you have the following line earlier in your code

```
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return from that handler function, the browser will proceed to carry out the normal behavior of the "submit" event, which is to submit the form.

You can change your "abort" return statements to

```
return false;
```